# React - Passing a new value to an input field from an output component with an onClick

Tags: reactjs, onclick, react-hooks, input-field

I need to be able to get the output value into a new input field when I click a button and I'm unclear on how to achieve this. I'm fairly new to React and using functional components with react hooks like useState.

I'm not sure how to write the handleClick function, so that when the button is clicked new-input component can have the value that was computed and displayed in the Output component.

This is my barebones code so far:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Output from "./Output.js"

export default function Calculator() {
  const [number1, setNumber1] = useState (0); 
  const [number2, setNumber2] = useState (0); 


  return (
    <div>

      <input id="first-number" value={number1} type="number" onChange={e => setNumber1(+e.target.value)}/>
      <input id="second-number" value={number2} type="number" onChange={e => setNumber2(+e.target.value)}/>

      <Output value={number1+number2}/>


      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click Here</button>

      <input id="new-input" />

    </div>
  )
}
```

My Output component:

```
import React from "react";

const Output = (props) => {
  return (
   <div className="outpout-box">
    {props.value}
   </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use another state, ex `result`:

```
export default function Calculator() {
  const [number1, setNumber1] = useState (0); 
  const [number2, setNumber2] = useState (0); 
  const [result, setResult] = useState(number1 + number2);

  const handleClick = event => {
    setResult(number1 + number2)
  }

  return (
    <div>

      <input id="first-number" value={number1} type="number" onChange={e => setNumber1(+e.target.value)}/>
      <input id="second-number" value={number2} type="number" onChange={e => setNumber2(+e.target.value)}/>

      <Output value={result}/>


      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click Here</button>

      <input id="new-input" />

    </div>
  )
}
```